# rxjs operators to collect strings from a source and partially emit them according to a pattern

Tags: typescript, rxjs, operators, observable

So I'm using typescript/RXJS/React-Native on a bluetooth-enabled project; I have a function which receives strings from a given peripheral but there are some caveats that I can't really avoid from this peripheral.

First, it communicated with me through a certain pattern of commands; namely, every command is of the form `/[a-zA-Z][^;]*;/` (aka. one alphabet character, followed by any number of characters, ending on a semicolon).

These commands may or may not be followed by whitespaces which are supposed to be ignored. Furthermore, these commands may or may not be sent concatenated: `a1234;bFGe4;` would be two commands `a1234;` and `bFGe4;` sent in the same message. However, there is a caveat: A command, if it's long enough, might be incomplete. For example, I might receive two messages `c444a;X132124122412431` and then `1234124;`, which should be translated into two separate commands `c444a;` and `X1321241224124311234124;`. This is due to a hardware limitation.

I managed to deal with this situation using an observable that keeps the ending of the last received string in itself:

```
const ANY_MSG = /[a-zA-Z][^;]*;/g

const messages$ = new Observable<string>(sub => {
  let previousMsg = "";

  // monitor messages is the function w/ a callback that receives messages from the device
  monitorMessages((err, msg) => {
    if (err) {
      return sub.error(err);
    }

    const currMsg = previousMsg + msg
    const matches = currMsg.match(ANY_MSG)

    let lastIndex = 0
    if(matches) {
      for(const match of matches) {
        sub.next(match)
        lastIndex += match.length
      }
    }
    previousMsg = currMsg.slice(lastIndex)
  });
});
```

This observable emits my messages as I expect: They are separated by semicolon and concatenated if they were partially received by the `monitorMessages` function.

The thing is, I feel like this function is hard to read and understand, and it would be better off if it was composed via `pipe`d functions from RXJS. In other words, I want to do something along these lines:

```
const messages$ = bindNodeCallback(monitorMessages).pipe(
  // ??????
);
```

But I can't figure out which operators I need to apply there(or even if I need to write my own), in the way that the following happens:

- Whenever `monitorMessages` emits a message, split it into two parts: the part before the last semicolon, and the part after the last semicolon of the message
- Emit all semicolon-separated commands from the first part, and store the second part
- Whenever `monitorMessages` emits again, concatenate the stored second part to the new string and make it go through the same process as before

Is this even possible purely through RXJS operators? maybe I need to create a new observable that works as a "storage" for the second part? I just feel the current approach(creating some sort of internal state for the Observable) is super weird and relatively hard to understand atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your implementation is fine. However, if you really want to implement it with operators, you can use [`scan`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api?query=scan) to maintain some state within the composed observable chain, like this:

```js
const messages$ = bindNodeCallback(monitorMessages).pipe(
  scan((acc, received) => {
    const data = acc.remainder + received;
    const messages = data.match(ANY_MSG);
    if (messages) {
      const length = messsages.reduce((total, message) => total + message.length, 0);
      return { messages, remainder: data.slice(length) };
    }
    return { messages: [], remainder: data };
  }, { messages: [], remainder: "" }),
  mergeMap(({ messages }) => messages)
);
```

And to emit your array of messages, you can use `mergeMap`, returning the array - as an array is an `ObservableInput`.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I was looking for. I assume the `remainder` on line 3 is meant to be `acc.remainder` right?
I just wanted to separate the Observable creation(ie. the 'bindNodeCallback') from its logic, and this works great for me. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I've fixed the answer.